# About accesing depth images using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ros, robotics, realsense

I have a array called `depth_msg` which has a lot of numbers that represents the depth values of a image. When I convert them in `cv2` message format,

I get this depth image,
[image]

And the actual image is ,
[image]

How can I get the depth value of the red and yellow bell peppers with the help of the depth image?

My code is,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv_bridge import CvBridge

def depth_clbck(depth_msg):

    bridge = CvBridge()
    image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(depth_msg,"32FC1")
    depth_array = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32)
    depth_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=0.05), cv2.COLORMAP_HSV)

    cv2.imshow('image', np.array(depth_colormap))
    cv2.waitKey()
```

How can I get the depth values of the red and yellow bell-peppers with the help of this depth array and this depth image?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the depth value for the red and yellow peeprs in thei mage, you will first have to segment the blobs for the two peppers fro mthe image. Once you have the segmented mask, you can simply obtain through slicing.

For segmentation, you can either manually segment out the peppers or using a image segmentation algorithm - this link shall help you get started:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.segmentation.html

Once a segmentation mask *mask* is obtained, *depth_array[mask>0]* will fetch you the depth pixels.